# Superclass type or subclass type

Tags: java, list, collections, linked-list

What is the difference of

```
LinkedList<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> l2 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Why does `l2` type don't have method `addFirst` while
`l1` type have method `addFirst`? even though they are both 
hold a `LinkedList` object?
Contrary to what I read from Gosling's "The Java Programming language"
which states that the object will be what you made it to be,
in this case I made it a `LinkedList` with `new LinkedList()` even though
it is of type List

How should I properly declare then?

```
Collection<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does l2 type don't have method addFirst while l1 type have method addFirst?

Because the compile-time type of `l2` is just `List<E>`, and `List<E>` doesn't declare the `addFirst` method.

As a simpler example, consider:

```
Object x = "hello";
int invalid = x.length(); // This is invalid
```

At execution time, `x` will refer to a `String` object, but the type of the variable itself is just `Object`, so you can't call the `String.length()` method.

It's very important to distinguish three different terms here:

- A *variable*, which has a type based on how it's declared
- A *reference* (e.g. the value of a reference-type variable)
- An *object* (which has a type)

The value of a variable (assuming it's not a primitive variable) is a reference. That reference can either be `null`, or it can refer to an object of a type which is assignment-compatible with the type of the variable.

So in the above example:

- The type of `x` is `Object`
- The value of `x` is a reference
- That reference refers to an object of type `String` at execution time

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you mean... I should always make sure that the type during compile-time should complement with the object pointed to by the reference during the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedList<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Here l1 is the instance of LinkedList

```
List<String> l2 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Here l2 is the instance of List

l2 does not have method addFirst because List interface does not contain that method while LinkedList contains that. But anytime in your code, you can cast your l2 to linkedList and can call addFirst() method.

Answer (score 0):

List l2 = new LinkedList();

This is useful when You  have a method that only takes an instance of `SuperClass`. Since `SubClass` *is a* `SuperClass`, you can use an instance of `SubClass` and treat it as `SuperClass`.

That's polymorphism. It allows you to change out the implementation of the class' internals without breaking the rest of your code.